# how to open dashcode in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

i have watched a site which has taught iphone application using dashcode.it says dashcode is a part of iphone sdk but i cant find how to open it?can anyone tell how to open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Developer/Applications/Dashcode.app